# Redis Cache on updating a table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, laravel-5.3

I am having trouble of thinking of a proper way of handling this "problem". I am implementing redis cache on my laravel 5.3 app.

I am caching the users data, but how would i handle when i update the users table later on? I was going to update the redis key with that users info, but then i started thinking what about the other queries (which i also cached) that i have in my repository which join to the users table. It would still be displaying old data.

As you can see, i feel like i am in a endless loop where i would have to update all queries where my table users is joined. I was also thinking to delete all redis using laravels `flush` helper everytime i updated my users tables, but i feel like it's bad practice.

Has anyone run into these kinds of problem? Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: How are you saving users data? On the whole like cache('users') or like individual ones? cache('users.1')?

Comment: individually, 'users.1', the part i am having trouble understanding is when i have a different query like 'posts with users', should i update that cache too? what happens when i have 10 other queries with the users table, do i update each cache, or just delete all cache from redis

Comment: same problem here, Redis cache data is updating in the testing server but not in production.